# Python: Is there a way to remove a character without regard to capitalization?

Tags: python, loops, refactoring

My code is supposed to remove vowels from the user inputted string. It works correctly, but I'm trying to see if there is a way to simplify my code. [A screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebdto.jpg)

I originally didn't have the line:

```
     elif i == "A" or i == "E" or i == "I" or i == "O" or i == "U":
        n.replace(i, "")
        output = output
```

but I added it because when my input contained capitalized vowels it would not remove the vowels because they were capitalized.

Is there a way to rewrite my code so I can remove the vowels that are both lowercase and capitalized without the extra lines?

Comment: Please post text as text, not a screenshot so it can be copy/paste/run.

Comment: `if i.lower() in "aeiou":`

Comment: See [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for an efficient way.  Use `str.maketrans('','','AEIOUaeiou')` to build the translation table.  The 3rd parameter is characters to delete.

Comment: How about `if i.lower() in "aeiou":`?

Answer (score 1):

You can check in lowercase, this way you do not duplicate comparisons:

```py
if i.lower() in 'aeiou':
    n.replace(i, "")
```

but you can write even simpler code with no loops using regular expression:

```py
import re

def remove_vowels(n):
    return re.sub(r'[aueoi]', '', n, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

It basically removes any char from the list [a, u, e, o, i], adding `flags=re.IGNORECASE` matches both lower and upper case letters, and replaces each letter with `''` basicaly removing it

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regular expressions, in particular the built-in [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function:

```
import re
text = "ThE quick brown fOx jumps over the lazy dog"
re.sub("[aeiou]","", text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

> 'Th qck brwn fx jmps vr th lzy dg'

The regular expression `[aeiou]` will match any vowel and then the flag `re.IGNORECASE` will allow the expression to match the upper case vowels as well. You could instead extend the pattern to `[AEIOUaeiou]`.

Answer (score 0):

(edited to fix)

Here is one way to do it:

```
word = input()

output = ""
for letter in word:
    if letter.casefold() not in "aeiou":
        output += letter

print(output)
```

to make it into a function:

```
def remove_vowels(word):
    output = ""
    for letter in word:
        if letter.casefold() not in "aeiou":
            output += letter
    return output
```

Comment: Your approach doesn't work. It removes only last vowel

Comment: oops, I'll fix it